# How to decorate an object in Java

Tags: java, decorator

**Quick Background**

I have a two lists of (large) POJOs being passed in to a method in which I need to ensure uniqueness across the two lists. The best solution I can see is construct two sets and check that their intersection is empty.

**The Problem**

For the context of this method, and this method alone, I need to override the `equals` and `hashcode` method of the POJOs in question.

**What I Am Looking For**

This seems like a prime candiate to decorate the existing objects. I have looked at [Guava's ForwardingObject](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingObject.html) but it seems best suited for delegating objects that implement a given interface which is not my case. In general, I am looking for a solution that ...

1. Avoids coping all of the fields in the large POJO (copy constructors).
2. Easy to understand and maintain
3. Avoids creating a whole new class that extends the POJO for the sake of this one method

Comment: Are you saying that the POJOs do not currently implement equals and hashcode already and you cannot change them to do so?

Comment: The decorator pattern really doesn't make too much sense without a common interface.  Extending the class is "yuck."

Comment: @Eric: No I am saying that the POJO's equals and hashcode don't make sense for this one method. Odd perhaps but it's not the first time I've wanted to define a context aware equality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just go with a wrapper class.

Create a new class that is instantiated with your POJO in the constructor. It doesn't copy the POJO, just holds onto the reference to the original. Then write equals and hashcode however you like in that wrapper class.

Something like this:

```
public class MySpecialWrapper{
  private final BigPojo delegate;

  public MySpecialWrapper(BigPojo pojo){
    this.delegate = pojo;
  }

  public int hashCode(){
    //insert special impl here.
  }

  public boolean equals(Object o){
    //insert special impl here.
  }
}
```

Put instances of the wrapper class into your Sets and use that for uniqueness verification. Add an accessor method (getDelegate) if you need to get access to the offending POJO in the case of a failure.

Comment: Looks pretty similar to Eric's answer, please see my comment there too.

Comment: I'm unaware of anything out there that would do this for you. However, as you can see, this is pretty small. Put in a nice comment at the top to clarify what this is for, and you should be golden. I respect the quest for re-use of that which is already defined. But, for something like this, you have to weigh that against the time spent in the search for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution is to create a wrapper class for each POJO class. The wrapper holds a reference to the POJO instance and defines equals and hashcode methods that calculate their values based on the appropriate fields in the POJO. Then you can use the normal Collections classes.

Comment: I am starting to think the same way. This may be trivial, but is there predefined wrapper class out there? I like to reuse what's already out there for ease of understanding and completeness.

Comment: +1 Like I said, you don't even have to wrap it, you can pre-calculate the `hashCode()` value and an identifier that will be compared in `equals()`.

Comment: @Andrew: Truly, for your case a wrapper is the simplest solution. You're not creating a delegate. As @biziclop said, you can calculate the values you need right in the constructor. And you don't necessarily have to include all the properties in your calculations, just whatever is unique to the object. So the wrapper doesn't have to be very complex. You could go even further and implement the Comparable interface and use the wrapper for sorting, if that's useful. Be sure to follow the advice in Items 7 and 8 in Effective Java...

Comment: @Andrew: Forgot... a predefined wrapper class would have to use reflection to calculate a unique hashcode and so you'd pay a performance penalty. A static class would be much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic proxy to wrap each element:

```
class VeryBigPOJO {}

interface PojoWrapper {
  VeryBigPOJO getPojo();
}

class MyHandler implements InvocationHandler {
    private VeryBigPOJO ob;

    public MyHandler( VeryBigPOJO ob ) {
        this.ob = ob;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args)
            throws Throwable {
        if( method.getName().equals( "getPojo") )
            return ob;
        if( method.getName().equals( "equals") )
            //calculate equals
        if( method.getName().equals( "hashCode") )
            //calculate hashCode
    }
}
```

Then wrap your objects into these dynamic proxies:

```
VeryBigPOJO pojo = ...;
PojoWrapper wrapper =  Proxy.newProxyInstance( MyHandler.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[] { PojoWrapper.class}, new MyWrapper( pojo ) )
```

And now you can add your `wrapper` objects to that `HashSet`.

However, wouldn't it be easier to construct a smaller, immutable `id` object out of the large pojo? It would certainly be more readable.